# Scala : Passing elements of a Dataframe from every row and get back the result in separate rows

Tags: scala, dataframe

In My requirment , i come across a situation where i have to pass 2 strings from my dataframe's 2 column and get back the result in string and want to store it back to a dataframe. 
Now while passing the value as string, it is always returning the same value. So in all the rows the same value is being populated. (In My case PPPP is being populated in all rows)

Is there a way to pass element (for those 2 columns) from every row and get the result in separate rows. 
I am ready to modify my function to accept Dataframe and return Dataframe OR accept arrayOfString and get back ArrayOfString but i dont know how to do that as i am new to programming. Can someone please help me.
Thanks.

```
def myFunction(key: String , value :String ) : String =   {

  //Do my functions and get back a string value2 and return this value2 string
value2

}



val DF2 = DF1.select (
  DF1("col1")
 ,DF1("col2")
 ,DF1("col5")    )
 .withColumn("anyName", lit(myFunction ( DF1("col3").toString()  , DF1("col4").toString() )))




/* DF1:

/*+-----+-----+----------------+------+
/*|col1 |col2 |col3     | col4 | col 5|
/*+-----+-----+----------------+------+
/*|Hello|5    |valueAAA | XXX  | 123  |
/*|How  |3    |valueCCC | YYY  | 111  |
/*|World|5    |valueDDD | ZZZ  | 222  |
/*+-----+-----+----------------+------+


/*DF2:

/*+-----+-----+--------------+
/*|col1 |col2 |col5| anyName |
/*+-----+-----+--------------+
/*|Hello|5    |123 | PPPPP   |
/*|How  |3    |111 | PPPPP   |
/*|World|5    |222 | PPPPP   |
/*+-----+-----+--------------+ 
*/
```

Comment: you have to use UDF() for such transformations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you define the function, you need to register them as udf(). The udf() function is available in org.apache.spark.sql.functions. check this out

```
scala> val DF1 = Seq(("Hello",5,"valueAAA","XXX",123),
     | ("How",3,"valueCCC","YYY",111),
     | ("World",5,"valueDDD","ZZZ",222)
     | ).toDF("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5")
DF1: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: int ... 3 more fields]

scala> val DF2 = DF1.select (  DF1("col1") ,DF1("col2") ,DF1("col5")    )
DF2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [col1: string, col2: int ... 1 more field]

scala> DF2.show(false)
+-----+----+----+
|col1 |col2|col5|
+-----+----+----+
|Hello|5   |123 |
|How  |3   |111 |
|World|5   |222 |
+-----+----+----+


scala> DF1.select("*").show(false)
+-----+----+--------+----+----+
|col1 |col2|col3    |col4|col5|
+-----+----+--------+----+----+
|Hello|5   |valueAAA|XXX |123 |
|How  |3   |valueCCC|YYY |111 |
|World|5   |valueDDD|ZZZ |222 |
+-----+----+--------+----+----+

scala> def myConcat(a:String,b:String):String=
     | return a + "--" + b
myConcat: (a: String, b: String)String

scala> 
scala> import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._

scala> val myConcatUDF = udf(myConcat(_:String,_:String):String)
myConcatUDF: org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction = UserDefinedFunction(<function2>,StringType,Some(List(StringType, StringType)))

scala> DF1.select (  DF1("col1") ,DF1("col2") ,DF1("col5"), myConcatUDF( DF1("col3"), DF1("col4"))).show()
+-----+----+----+---------------+
| col1|col2|col5|UDF(col3, col4)|
+-----+----+----+---------------+
|Hello|   5| 123|  valueAAA--XXX|
|  How|   3| 111|  valueCCC--YYY|
|World|   5| 222|  valueDDD--ZZZ|
+-----+----+----+---------------+


scala>
```

Comment: Could you please consider accepting the answer.. and upvote